# StackBlitz error import jpg "Import error, can't find file

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting an import error in my react project.

See my project.
[text](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-d4lkns?file=src%2Fprojects%2F03-like-my-photo%2FLikePhotoApp.jsx)

(Ps. when working offline with VSCode the project is not giving the error and works)

Please help.

I have moved the file dog.jpg to other folders and changed the path.
No solution found.